# YII2 JOIN неккоректно работает по сравнению с чистым sql

Tags: php, sql, yii2, join

```
SELECT *
FROM food 
JOIN order_food ON order_food.id_food = food.id_food
GROUP BY food.name_food
ORDER BY COUNT( food.name_food ) DESC Limit 5');
```

вот запрос он выводит 5 популярных блюд
и нормально все выдает таблица первая на картинке

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand( '
SELECT food.name_food, COUNT( food.name_food ) as cnt_food,
 order_food.id_food, order_food.id_order
FROM food 
JOIN order_food ON order_food.id_food = food.id_food
GROUP BY food.name_food
ORDER BY COUNT( food.name_food ) DESC Limit 5' );
$models = $command->queryAll();
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $models ); $i++ ) {
$models[$i]['place'] = $i + 1;
}

$dataProvider3 = new ArrayDataProvider([
 'allModels' => $models,
'sort' => [

    'attributes' => [
        'name_food',
        'id_food',
        'cnt_food',
        'matches' => [ 'default' => SORT_DESC ],
    ],
],
'pagination' => [ 'pageSize' => 100 ],
 ]);
```

Пришлось удалить старое изображение, кармы не хватает
[image: То что показывает консоль, потом pmd, и уii2]

Первая картинка, это консоль, привел  таблицу, для наглядности. Вторая картинка, то что выдал phpmyadmin, третья, то что выдал yii2.(в yii2 чтобы уместилась таблица на картинке, просто не выводил GRIDVIEW последнюю колонку.)

Comment: А может это чистый запрос не так работает? Может он закэшировал запрос первый и выдает по нему теперь. Надо попробовать из консоли запустить запрос и посмотреть там что выдаст.

Comment: я попробовал и просто JOIN обеих таблиц, результаты разнятся. В результатирующую таблицу из YII, выводятся дополнительные строки. И вот эти дополнительные строки, в дальнейшем подсчитывает COUNT, и выводит то, что выводит.

Comment: Я вас попросил ваш так называемый "чистый запрос" (**НЕ тот что в yii** )....выполнить в обычной консоли. Вы это сделали?

Comment: Я выполнил "чистый запрос" Картинку в запросе обновил. Там результаты чистого, pmd и yii2